# How do I pass and change visibility between components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-hooks, use-effect

I have a function as userManage.jsx and it includes Search component. Search.jsx returns filterbox, searchbox and new button. I call Search component in userManage.jsx like

```
const [newUserModalVisible, setNewUserModalVisible] = useState(false)

            <Search
                onCallback={onFormCallback}
                dataAPI={dataAPI}
                visible={newUserModalVisible}
                colorAPI={colorAPI}
            />
```

In Search component, I want to change visible when I clicking new button. How can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll pass a function down to Search as a prop, and then call that function when the click happens.

For example, if you're ok with giving  full control to change the state, you can pass `setNewUserModalVisible` directly:

```
<Search
  onCallback={onFormCallback}
  dataAPI={dataAPI}
  visible={newUserModalVisible}
  setVisible={setNewUserModalVisible}
  colorAPI={colorAPI}
/>

// in search:
const Search = (props) => {

  // ...
  <div onClick={() => props.setVisible(true)}> 
}
```

Or, if you want to restrict what the Search component can do to your state, you can create a new function and pass that down. For example, this function can only be used to set visible to true:

```
<Search
  onCallback={onFormCallback}
  dataAPI={dataAPI}
  visible={newUserModalVisible}
  makeVisible=(() => setNewUserModalVisible(true))}
  colorAPI={colorAPI}
/>
```